# Running individual test functions using docker compose

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have my flask webapp up and running in Docker and trying to implement some unit tests and having trouble executing the tests. While my containers are up and running, I run the following:

```
docker-compose run app python3 manage.py test
```

to try to execute my `test` function in `manage.py`:

```
import unittest
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from myapp import app, db


cli = FlaskGroup(app)

@cli.command()
def recreate_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()

@cli.command()
def test():
    """ Runs the tests without code coverage"""
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('myapp/tests', pattern='test*.py')
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        return 0
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

But since I have a `start.sh` in my `Dockerfile` it just executes my Gunicorn `start.sh` but it doesn't run my test. I just see the following in the console, but no trace of my `test()` function.

```
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
[2018-12-08 01:21:08 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Wait until MySQL is ready
while ! mysqladmin ping -h"db" -P"3306" --silent; do
    echo "Waiting for MySQL to be up..."
    sleep 1
done

source venv/bin/activate
# Start Gunicorn processes
echo Starting Gunicorn.

exec gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi --reload --chdir usb_app --timeout 9999 --workers 3 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - --capture-output --log-level debug
```

Does anyone know why or how I can execute the test function in an existing container without having to start the Gunicorn workers again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume `start.sh` is your entrypoint. If not, you can make it as an entrypoint instead of putting it in `CMD`.

We can override the entrypoint script using `--entrypoint` argument, I do it as below -

```
docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "python3 manage.py test" app
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, the `start.sh` is my entrypoint. `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/home/user/app/start.sh"]` However, my entry point also does `source venv/bin/activate`, can I just do it in the override as well? Cause just by running the command you mentioned above give me an error `ImportError: No module named 'flask'`

Comment: I added my `start.sh` as well in my post for reference.

Comment: Maybe you can create another script like `test.sh`, copy it using Dockerfile & then override it in entrypoint something like `docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint "sh /test.sh" app` . I haven't tested this.